# Определение типа шаблона через конструктор

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

В c++17 ведь можно было через конструкторы определить тип шаблона?
Т.е вот так:

```
template<typename T>
struct Widget{
Widget(T value){};
}
```

А потом компилятор мог в такой строке кода сам определить тип как int:

```
Widget a(1); //ну или pair a('a', 'b');
```

Просто у меня сейчас при попытке так сделать вылезла ошибка, что нужно ввести список аргументов шаблона

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, то, что что-то есть в стандарте - не означает, что оно же есть в любом компиляторе. Так сказать, мало ли что написано в Конституции, важнее, как оно в жизни... :)

Что касается VC++, то можно посмотреть [таблицу его соответствия стандартам](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/visual-cpp-language-conformance), и там увидеть, что сия возможность реализована только в версии 15.7 (какая у вас?) и требует использования ключа `/std:c++17` или `/std:c++latest` (вы использовали?).

У меня на версии 15.8.2 с `/std:c++latest` вполне компилируется.